# Bounded variation, derivative question.

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I am charged with the following

Assume $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is of bounded variation.  Show that for all $0<h<b-a$

$\int_a^{b-h} |f(x+h) - f(x)| dx = h V_f(a,b)$

I am allowed the fact that $f$ having bounded variation implies that $|f'|$ is integrable.  It seems like that should play a role but I'm having difficulty putting it together.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I am charged with the following" - I hope the trial goes well!

Answer (score 0):

The equality doesn't hold.

Take for $f$ the sine function on the interval $[0, 4\pi]$ and $h=2\pi$. You have

$$\int_a^{b-h} |f(x+h) - f(x)| dx =\int_0^{2\pi} \vert \sin(x+2\pi)-\sin x \vert \ dx=0$$ while $h V_f(0,4\pi)=16\pi$.

Comment: That's a fitting handle there!  Thanks for the example.